# In agGrid (angular2) how do I make my cellEditor Row Dependent. For example I might want to use a dropdown for a specific row

Tags: ag-grid

In agGrid (angular2), how do I make my cellEditor Row Dependent.  For example I might want to use a dropdown for cells in a specific row and a numeric for the rest!

Comment: Elaborate your question in details

Answer (score 0):

You can use a component selector.

Have a look at this:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/#many-renderers-one-column

Hope this helps